# Hiding the rows in uitableview- iOS8

Tags: ios, mobile, ios8

I have an UITableView with Dynamic properties content and number of prototype cells  = 1;
Number of sections  = 16;
Number of rows = 16;
Is it possible like, in section 1- only 1st row should be visible; in section2- only second row should be visible; in section3- only third row should be visible and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to "hide" a row in an UITableView, just return 0 for its height, and the regular one for the others which aren't hidden.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (/* hide this specific cell */) {
         return 0;
    }
    return regularCellHeight;
}
```

Following what did you say, your condition could be:

```
indexPath.section != indexPath.row
```

Answer (score 0):

You should manage your all your content through your datasource array no hidden your cells.

If you have to change (add/remove) some specific row without reload the entire table maybe you should take a look this methods.

```
[_tableView beginUpdates];
[_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexToAdd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[_tableView endUpdates];
```